# How to find the correct version of an installed package in /nix/store

Tags: nix

I installed `dovecot` and with it came a tool called `maildirlock` that I would like to use. It's not in PATH, but it is in /nix/store. Multiple times in different versions, of course (and they can be found with `find /nix/store/ -iname "maildirlock"`).

How do I identify the version matching the currently installed (and running) dovecot? What is the idiomatic way for doing so? Is there a tool for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package puts it in `${pkgs.dovecot}/libexec/dovecot/maildirlock`, so it's not even in directory that is normally put on $PATH.

You can certainly work around it in some ways, e.g. modify your `configuration.nix` accordingly:

```
systemPackages = [
  (pkgs.runCommand "maildirlock" {}
    "mkdir -p $out/bin && ln -s ${pkgs.dovecot}/libexec/dovecot/maildirlock $out/bin/"
  )
];
```

Comment: For me the take away message is that `pkgs.dovecot` evaluates to the correct path in `/nix/store` where `dovecot` and thus `maildirlock` is installed. Thanks!